# how many listen directives (mode tcp) i can have in haproxy?

Tags: haproxy, apache-mesos

how many listen directives is too many for haproxy configuration on a single node? What are the most important resources to monitor?

is 50 times the

```
listen qwerty213
  bind *:9124
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  balance leastconn
     server zxcv 10.20.0.13:31527 check inter 3000
     [...]
```

too many?  Or 100? (each one has several backend servers too)

Is there any limit after which haproxy performance deteriorates due to having a great number of open local ports which are connected to backend servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thousands should be fine, the total number of health checks on backends may become an issue but ports are not.
For a definitive answer you might want to try the HAProxy mailing list.